# Why is it that the code below behaves differently in Java 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java

The code below

```
public class Test16Jit {
  public static void main(String[] s) {
      int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int i = 0;
      long li = 0;
      while (i >= 0) {
          i++;
          li++;
          if (i > max) {
              System.out.println("i is : " + i);
              System.out.println("max is : " + max);
              System.out.println("Woo!! something really went wrong");
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Value of i: " + i);
      System.out.println("Total # of iterations: " + li);      
  }
}
```

Outputs below in java 1.7x

```
Value of i: -2147483648
Total # of iterations: 2147483648
```

Outputs below in Java 1.6x

```
i is : 2147483636
max is : 2147483647
Woo!! something really went wrong
Value of i: -2147483648
Total # of iterations: 2147483648
```

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Also if I change

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; -> final int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

It behaves exactly same in 1.6x and 1.7x

Comment: Do you get a difference in behaviour from the simpler code `int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE; int i = 2147483636; System.out.println(i > max);`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I haven't tested, but I'm guessing this is supposed to be a JIT bug.

Comment: That prints false @AndyTurner

Comment: @Puru-- could You please provide the exact `-version`s of both JVMs you are running th ecode on?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_65" and java version "1.7.0_67"

Comment: There's something similar: http://web.archive.org/web/20120119112826/http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7049186 - I guess JIT does not like MAX_VALUEs :)

Comment: @Puru-- - could you post the whole version output? I'm curious if I can match, say, hotspot version, to a bug request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like one of many examples of a family of errors related to this one caused by the JIT compilation (I picked this one due to similarity of code, feel free to explore others - they are quite interesting!):

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6196102

> EVALUATION
>
> Problem is with canonicalization of loop exit test in preparation for
>   loop transformation.
>
> `do while (++i <= limit)`
>
> becomes
>
> `do while (++i < limit+1)`
>
> This isn't correct when limit is maxInt.

Some issues were fixed in 1.7, which could explain your results.

Comment: Very good find. However I am still scratching my head a little bit why would this happen at the very end when integer overflow?